# pagination with codiegniter and bootstrap links are not coming up properly

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

i have used pagination in one of my codiegniter page where i want to show the pagination links in bootstrap class the links are showing up properly on first page but when i click on link2 the links than not coming up properly .please show me the way how can i adjust them .
here is my view page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<base href="<?php echo base_url()?>" />
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>User Handling</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<?php
if(isset($new_post))
{
    foreach($new_post as $row)
    {
        echo '<h1>'.$row->tittle.'</h1>';

        echo '<p style="background-color:#CCC;">'.$row->post.'</p>';
        $row->id;
        echo '<a href="index/post_edit/'.$row->id.'">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo '<a href="index/delete_post/'.$row->id.'">Delete</a>';
        echo '<br/>';

    }
}
```

Problem is here in pagination links

```
if(isset($link)){
 echo '<ul class="pagination"><li>'.$link.'</li></ul>';
 echo '<br/>';
}
else{
    echo'no link have been fired';
}
?>
<a href="<?php echo 'index';?>"><button class="btn btn-large btn-success">Home</button></a>
</div>
</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

The controller function from where i am passing those links.

```
function show_post()
   {
     $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index/show_post';
      $config['total_rows'] = $this->user->record_count();
      $config['per_page'] = 3; 
      $config['uri_segment']=3;
      $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
      $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

      $data['link']=$this->pagination->create_links();
      $data['new_post']=$this->user->getpost($config['per_page'],$page);


     $this->load->view("post",$data);
   }
```

The first page where the pagination is correct.
[image: correct pagination view]

The second page where the pagination is not correct.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagination with codiegniter and bootstrap is quite beautiful done in this link follow the link along [pagination with codiegniter and bootstrap](https://gist.github.com/mikedfunk/3504432)

All the things are done by the author you only need to adjust the code and it will work for sure if it wont work let me know than.

Comment: awesome @Aitazaz Khan you made my day as you said every thing is done in it.Thanks Alot Thanks Thanks Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not an expert on the pagination class for codeigniter, but I would imagine you should read the section entitled "Customizing the Pagination," and "Adding Enclosing Markup"

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

If you want to change how the links are displayed (what html surrounds them, etc..) I believe you need to use the config options provided.

See if that helps.

Ok editing this to add some code for you...This really is all explained in the doc though.

```
// If you want to wrap your pagination in something
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

// If you want to wrap the "go to first" link
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="whateverboostrap">';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

// If you want to wrap the "go to last" link
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="whateverboostrap">';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

// If you want to wrap the next link
$config['next_link'] = 'Next';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="whateverboostrap">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

// If you want to wrap the previous link
$config['prev_link'] = 'Last';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="whateverboostrap">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

// Wrap/style active link
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active whateverboostrap">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';

// Wrap the 'digit' link.
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="whateverboostrap">';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

Comment: hmmmmm but for styling i am using bootstrap i have seen many things for styling but i have to work with bootstrap that is a head ace any how thanks for sending me the link

Comment: Bootstrap or not, you are just applying classes.  You just need to use the config options and specify the html (including the classes) that are surrounding your pagination.

Comment: @Vicky Added code example to answer...obviously you wouldn't use the "whateverbootstrap" class..you would add whatever classes make sense...but that is how you would do it.  Then just echo $link and don't wrap it with anything in your view as all of the wrapping is done inside the configuration.

Comment: oops sorry you have send me the same code as it was in the link